# jade not compiling in meanjs 0.4.2

Tags: node.js, meanjs

partial.server.route.js

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var partial = require('../controllers/partial.server.controller');
    app.get('modules/:module/client/views/:view*', partial.render);
};
```

partial.server.controller.js

```
exports.render = function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.path);
    res.render('.'+req.path);
};
```

in use

```
header(data-ng-include="'modules/core/client/views/header.client.view.jade'")
```

it show as plain text

please help me thank you.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors that might suggest what the issue is, have you looked into these errors yet if any exist?

Comment: not have error. but it's show "nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .container // Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display .navbar-header button.navbar-toggle.collapsed(type='button'..." in html element

Comment: i try to force render this file in  core.server.controller --> exports.renderIndex  it's work.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Jade's own `include` mechanism like:

```
header
    include modules/core/client/views/header.client.view
```

Also I'm not sure you can use the `ng-include` directive with jade templates. I believe you should be using html files instead.